# AttributeError when patching class variable when mocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I have this file structure

```
mocking_module
    - sample_class.py
    - class_util.py
    - test_base_class_attribute_override.py
```

And I defined a class like this. It has a class variable called base_url

sample_class.py

```
class SampleClass():
    base_url = "http://example.com"

    def get_base_url(self):
        return "base url {}".format(SampleClass.base_url)
```

And a utility class that uses the SampleClass

class_util.py

```
from mocking_module.sample_class import SampleClass

def do_something():
    sample_class = SampleClass()
    return sample_class.get_base_url()
```

I wanted to patch the SimpleClass base_url  class instance variable so in my test case I am doing this

test_base_class_attribute_override.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import Mock
from mocking_module import class_util


class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object("mocking_module.class_util.SampleClass", "base_url", "http://override.com")
    def test_class_variable_override(self):

        print("url = {}".format(class_util.do_something()))
```

But I am getting an error like this:

```
AttributeError: mocking_module.class_util.SampleClass does not have the attribute 'base_url'
```

Any thoughts what is wrong?

Comment: If you want to set the ``base_url`` again,why don't you set a function in your ``SampleClass`` to change the ``base_url``.Or don't you want to change your ``SampleClass``?

Comment: I want to mock it in my unit test not set its attribute.